# Integral of the Sinc product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let us consider the following integral
$$
B_n = \int_0^\infty \prod_{k=1,3,5,\dots}^n\frac{\sin (x/k)}{x/k}dx
$$

By definition, `Sinc[x] == Sin[x]/x`, therefore

```
B[n_?OddQ] := Integrate[Product[Sinc[x/k], {k, 1, n, 2}], {x, 0, Infinity}]

B /@ Range[1, 13, 2]
```

> ```
> {Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2}
> ```

OK, everything is fine. But...

```
B[15]
```

> ```
> 467807924713440738696537864469 Pi/935615849440640907310521750000
> ```

What's going on?

Comment: Not very far though `N[(467807924713440738696537864469 \[Pi])/
  935615849440640907310521750000 - Pi/2]`.

Comment: I don't know if it is correct, but you can calculate the indefinite integral, then take the limits; this will match your `B[15]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks How did you calculate the indefinite for B[15]? I aborted after a few minutes of waiting for `Integrate[..., {x,0,Infinity}]`

Comment: @ssch I used `ind = Integrate[(
   2027025 Sin[x/15] Sin[x/13] Sin[x/11] Sin[x/9] Sin[x/7] Sin[x/
     5] Sin[x/3] Sin[x])/x^8, x];`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks, I'll give that a go. (Too late to edit my previous comment, I used `{x,0,b}` not `{x,0,Infinity}`)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Borwein integrals

As Eckhard wrote in comments `B[n]` is the n-th [Borwein integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral).

(The letter `B` was not accidental :) )

This funny properties of Borwein integrals is related to the Fourier transform of `Sinc` function

```
FourierTransform[Sinc[x], x, k]
```

> ```
> 1/2 Sqrt[Pi/2] (Sign[1 - k] + Sign[1 + k])
> ```

```
Plot[%, {k, -2, 2}, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

which is the box function. The result is $\pi/2$ while the sum
$$
1/3+1/5+\dots+1/n < 1.
$$
If $n \ge 15$ the sum exceeds $1$ and the result becomes

$$
B_n = \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi \bigg(\sum_{k=3,5,\ldots}^n\frac{1}{k} -1\biggr)^\frac{n-1}{2}\prod_{k=3,5,\dots}^n\frac{k}{k-1}.
$$

For $n=15$ it is equal to

$$
\frac{467807924713440738696537864469}{935615849440640907310521750000}\pi.
$$

As a prank, Jonathan Borwein reported this to Maple, claiming there was a bug in the software. Maple computer scientist Jacques Carette spent 3 days trying to figure out the problem. Then he realized: There was no bug! That's what these integrals really equal!

The Borwein brothers are the same guys who noticed that the integral

$$
   \int_0^\infty \cos(2x) \cos(x) \cos(x/2) \cos(x/3) \cos(x/4) \dots dx
$$

matches $\pi/8$ up to $43$ decimal places, but is not equal to $\pi/8$. So you've got to be careful with these guys!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I already exceed the daily upvotes limit :)

Comment: Nice work.  I expect that will happen quite often with you.

Comment: So, you knew all this before posting your question ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Not everything, I read technical literature when prepare the answer. Sorry I wasted your time, but I hope it was fun to explore these integrals.

Comment: Please don't be sorry, I learned new things and it's great to have fun.

Comment: I might as well link to [this](http://mathoverflow.net/a/11607)... one of the comments in that linked answer is terribly interesting. :)