# How do I evaluate a symbolic integral involving Hermite polynomials?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, polynomials

I want to test a difficult integral : Integral on all reals of some complicated function involving the Hermitian polynomials, exponentials, squares, factorials, and being general considering any Hermitian polynomials. I know the answer (it's ridiculously short compared with the statement) and just wanted to check. But why *Mathematica* doesn't calculate my integral ? (I'm quite new on the system and don't understand what causes the trouble) :

```
Integrate[(HermiteH[n, x/a]*Exp[-x^2/(2 a^2)]/((n!)^(1/2) (Pi a^2)^(1/4)))^2*x^2,
          {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
          Assumptions :> {Element[n, Integers], Element[a, Reals], a > 0}]
```

And getting as a result:

> ```
> Integrate[ x^2 Exp[-(x^2/(2 a^2))]^2 HermiteH[n, x/a]^2/(Sqrt[a^2] Sqrt[Pi] n!), 
>            {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions :> {n ∈ Integers, a ∈ Reals, a > 0}]
> ```

What do I have to change to get an answer?

Comment: Perhaps writing exp with a capital E will help?

Comment: Even after the correction in `exp` to `Exp`, it is not possible to get analytical solution. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fXJp0.png) after about 3 minutes trying... also Maple 17 not able to do it. To help find such syntax errors, I always look at the equation for the green colored symbols (or is this blue colored? I always mix green with blue). If the symbol is not black colored, then it means Mathematica does not know about it. You could have seen that `exp` was green colored, this means Mathematica does know about it.

Answer (score 4):

One can observe that given `n` *Mathematica* can evaluate the above integral symbolically assuming e.g. `a > 0` (we needn't assume `a ∈ Reals` since the former assumption implies it). Thus finding e.g. the first `5` integrals we can make use `FindSequenceFunction`:

```
intherm[a_, n_] =
  FindSequenceFunction[ 
    Table[{n, Integrate[ E^(-x^2/a^2) x^2 HermiteH[n, x/a]^2/(n! Sqrt[(a^2)] Sqrt[π]), 
                         {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> a > 0]}, 
          {n, 0, 5}], n] // Simplify
```

> ```
>  2^(-1 + n) a^2 (1 + 2 n)
> ```

```
TraditionalForm[2^(-1 + n) a^2 (1 + 2 n)]
```

[image]

Let's check the result for a large number `n` e.g. `n = 131`:

```
With[{n = 131}, 
     Integrate[(E^(-(x^2/a^2)) x^2 HermiteH[n, x/a]^2)/(n! Sqrt[(a^2)] Sqrt[π]), 
               {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> a > 0] == 2^(-1 + n) a^2 (1 + 2 n)]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

There are different approaches e.g. exploiting recurrence relations between Hermite polynomials, but this one is quite simple and straightforward therefore there's no need for further considerations of the issue.

Comment: [I'm not entirely convinced :)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32599/integral-of-the-sinc-product)

Answer (score 2):

It is able to do the integration for fixed `n`.

```
hermInt[n_] := Integrate[(HermiteH[n, x/a]*
  Exp[-x^2/(2 a^2)]/((n!)^(1/2) (Pi a^2)^(1/4)))^2* x^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions :> {Element[a, Reals], a > 0}]
```

Here are the first 10:

```
hermInt[#] & /@ Range[10]
{3 a^2, 10 a^2, 28 a^2, 72 a^2, 176 a^2, 416 a^2, 960 a^2, 2176 a^2, 4864 a^2, 10752 a^2}
```

If we look at these coefficients they form a nice pattern:

```
FindSequenceFunction[{3, 10, 28, 72, 176, 416, 960, 2176, 4864, 10752}, n]
2^(-1 + n) (1 + 2 n)
```

Comment: You've given a wonderful idea !