# Integral over squared Hermite polynomial

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, physics

I would like to calculate the uncertainty of the nth Eigenstate of a 1-dim harmonic oscillator. To obtain the result I have to compute the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi^* x^2 \psi \:dx\,,$$ with $$\psi(n,x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} H_n(x)}{\pi^{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{2^n n!}}\,,$$ where $H_n(x)$ is the Hermite polynomial (degree n) in the physicist version (as implemented in Mathematica). In Mathematica this equals to the Integral over

```
(2^-n E^-x^2 x^2 HermiteH[n, x]^2)/(Sqrt[π] n!)
```

Doing this manually gives $1/2+n$, but i can't get Mathematica to solve this integral without specifying $n$. I used `

```
Assuptions=n ∈ Integers && n >= 0
```

Is there anyway to compute similar integrals with Mathematica?

Edit: Thanks for you answer, but I should have mentioned, that I'm looking for a way to let Mathematica solve such problems analytical.

Comment: Closely related or a duplicate [How do I evaluate a symbolic integral involving Hermite polynomials?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34440/how-do-i-evaluate-a-symbolic-integral-involving-hermite-polynomials).

Comment: You could code up (50) or (51) from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way without struggling with the integral:

```
FindSequenceFunction[
 Table[Integrate[(2^-n E^-x^2 x^2 HermiteH[n, x]^2)/(Sqrt[π] n!), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}],
       {n, 1, 5}], n]
(*
 1/2 (1 + 2 n)
*)
```

Comment: Is there any way to let Mathematica solve this problem analytical?

Comment: @Gebbo Not AFAIK